# Karma tests works with PhantomJs but not with Chrome

Tags: karma-runner

Runing karma tests in Phantom works fine but in Chrome not. All I change in karma.config is `browsers: ['PhantomJS'],` to `browsers: ['Chrome'],`.
If I change it I have 0 tests executed and `Test failed`.

Here is my Chrome response:
[image]

Response with Phantom:
[image]

Here is my karma.config.js

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Jan 16 2017 13:32:24 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon', 'fixture'],
        files: [
            'spec/**/*.spec.ts',
            'spec/fixtures/**/*.html',
        ],
        exclude: [],
        webpack: {
            module: webpackConfig.module,
            resolve: webpackConfig.resolve,
            plugins: [
                new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                    $: "jquery",
                    jQuery: "jquery",
                    "window.jQuery": "jquery",
                    Tether: 'tether',
                    "window.Tether": 'tether'
                })
            ],
        },
        preprocessors: {
            "spec/**/*.ts": ['webpack'],
            'spec/**/*.html': ['html2js'],
            'spec/**/*.json': ['json_fixtures']
        },
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        // browsers: ['Chrome'],
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        singleRun: true,
        concurrency: Infinity
    })
};
```

And package:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.34",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/karma-fixture": "^0.2.2",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.37",
    "@types/raty": "^2.7.26",
    "@types/sinon": "^1.16.34",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "karma": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-fixture": "^0.2.6",
    "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-json-fixtures-preprocessor": "0.0.6",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
    "karma-typescript": "^2.1.6",
    "karma-typescript-preprocessor2": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.0.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "sinon": "^1.17.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.6"
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding a mime configuration to karma.conf fixed a similar issue for me:

To debug in Chrome define in karma config:

```
autowatch:true
```

and define:

```
singleRun: false
```

Start your karma test and open in Chrome a page to the karma-server.

The following error was shown in the console:

```
Refused to execute script from   
'http://localhost:9876/base/src/app/search-persons/search-
persons.component.spec.ts?fe78e0d6a85c32fb65115ec3fd4e171b9f39ded7' 
because its MIME type ('video/mp2t') is not executable.
```

The mime config that fixed this for me:

```
mime: {
    'text/x-typescript': ['ts']
},
```